# Customize Ant design with Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, less, antd

I am using ant design in my next.js project. but I want to customize it, for example: " @primary-color: orange; "
I searched the internet and installed all the necessary npm packages, but since I have no webpack knowledge, I got different errors every time I tried. I tried many different codes in next.config.js but I got different errors for all of them. Can someone please explain to me how to do this?

here my folder tree :
[image]

and here my next.config.js file :
**I would like to state in advance that I do not know anything about webpack.**

```
const withSass = require("@zeit/next-sass");
const withLess = require("@zeit/next-less");
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css");

const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";

// fix: prevents error when .less files are required by node
if (typeof require !== "undefined") {
  require.extensions[".less"] = (file) => {};
}

module.exports = withCSS({
  cssModules: true,
  cssLoaderOptions: {
    importLoaders: 1,
    localIdentName: "[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
  },
  ...withLess(
    withSass({
      lessLoaderOptions: {
        javascriptEnabled: true,
      },
    })
  ),
});
```

and here my error :

```
yarn run v1.22.17
warning ../../../package.json: No license field
$ next dev
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
Warning: Built-in CSS support is being disabled due to custom CSS configuration being detected.
See here for more info: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/built-in-css-disabled

TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'styles')
    at module.exports (/Users/hashim/Desktop/bakucosy/bakucosy-app/node_modules/@zeit/next-css/css-loader-config.js:25:56)
    at Object.webpack (/Users/hashim/Desktop/bakucosy/bakucosy-app/node_modules/@zeit/next-css/index.js:15:36)
    at Object.getBaseWebpackConfig [as default] (/Users/hashim/Desktop/bakucosy/bakucosy-app/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack-config.js:1379:32)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/Users/hashim/Desktop/bakucosy/bakucosy-app/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:74:20)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/Users/hashim/Desktop/bakucosy/bakucosy-app/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:74:20)
    at async HotReloader.start (/Users/hashim/Desktop/bakucosy/bakucosy-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/hot-reloader.js:325:25)
    at async DevServer.prepare (/Users/hashim/Desktop/bakucosy/bakucosy-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:290:9)
    at async /Users/hashim/Desktop/bakucosy/bakucosy-app/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-dev.js:128:9
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
➜  bakucosy-app git:(master) ✗
```

Comment: `@zeit/next-css` and `@zeit/next-sass` have been deprecated and are no longer needed since Next.js has built-in support for CSS/Sass. I'd recommend using [next-with-less](https://github.com/elado/next-with-less) or [next-plugin-antd-less](https://github.com/SolidZORO/next-plugin-antd-less) plugins to handle Less.